# как перегуризить/разширить интерфейс что бы он стал гибридным

Tags: typescript

```
interface A {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

type B = A | Record<keyof A, null>;
```

**после значения первого ключа ts определяет какой интерфейс юзается и это логично, но как сделать, чтобы смешанный вариант тоже работал?**

```
const obj: B = {
  age: null,
  name: 'some'
}

Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'null'
```

Comment: Ээ, а что надо-то в результате?

Comment: @AlexeyTen уже внизу ответили, спасибо за помошь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я понял, вы хотите каждому свойству из `interface A` добавить возможность в `type B` присваивать `null`.

В вашем коде вы используете [Record](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) после которого у `B` это тип `interface A` или

```
{
  name: null,
  age: null
}
```

Вот так это выглядит `type B` если раскрыть `Record`:

```
type B = A | {
    [K in keyof A]: null;
}
```

То есть у вас тип `B` это или объект типа `A` или объект у которого все свойства `A` должны быть типа `null`. А вы в своем примере смешиваете. Да вы про это и написали, я просто немного объяснил.

Так вот, можно попробовать сделать так:

```
type B = {
  [K in keyof A]: A[K] | null;
}
```

Таким образом мы позволяем каждое свойство устанавливать в `null`.

P.s. я мог очень глупо объяснить, и путаться в словах, я с `typescript` пока мало знаком, но надеюсь более менее объяснил.